# Is set S is field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Under the matrix addition and multipliaction  ,the set $S= \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}  x & y \\ -\overline x & \overline y \end{bmatrix} : x, y \in 
 \mathbb{C}\right\}$ is

Choose the correct option

$1.$ Division ring

$2$ Field

I thinks  both option 1)  and 2)  are correct   because   all propeties of field are satisfies  i have checked its

Is its true ?

Comment: Perhaps that you meant $-\overline y$ and $\overline x$ in the second row. Otherwise, the product of two elements of $S$ doesn0t have to belong to $S$.

Comment: No  @JoséCarlosSantos    sir  i mean   $-\bar x$  and $ \bar y$

Comment: Well, aside from the fact that S isn't closed under multiplication, the matrix with $(x,y)=(i,1)$ is not invertible.

Comment: is not closed by multiplication

Comment: if $x=a+bi$ and $y=c+di$, then determine the matrix is $2ac+2bd$. So the determine equal to zero in many cases.

Comment: The identity Matrix is not even in $S$.  When you say you checked all the properties...which properties, exactly, did you check?  How did you check them?

Comment: thanks  u.. @lulu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question makes no sense, because $M=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}i&0\\i&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ belongs to $S$, but $M^2$ doesn't.